# Rank of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+px$

Tags: elliptic-curves

I need to prove that the rank of the curve $y^2=x^3+px$ is $0$, if $p\equiv 7 \pmod {16}$ is a prime.
Using the standard technique, we need to show that none of the following two equations admits an integer solution in M, N and e (with M, N and e pairwise coprime; M, e non-zero):
$2M^4-2pe^4=N^2$
$4M^4-pe^4=N^2$

I have got this after going modulo 16. But, $2M^4-2pe^4=N^2$ and $4M^4-pe^4=N^2$ do
admit solutions in $Z/16Z$

Answer (score 3):

This is shown in Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Chapter X, Section 6 (The curve $Y^2=X^3+DX$), Proposition 6.2.

Answer (score 3):

For $2M^4-2pe^4=N^2$, we see that $N=2n$ for some integer $n$. Substituting in the equation and reducing by 2 we get $2n^2=M^4-pe^4$. Now if $p\equiv 7(mod 16)$ then we get
$n^2\equiv -3 (mod 16)$ so $n^2\equiv -3 (mod 8)$ which  is a contradiction. Because
$x^2\equiv 0,1,4(mod 8) $ for integer $x$.