# Rank of Elliptic Curve, $Y^2=x^3+px$ where $p$ is prime is either $0,1,2$

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am following book "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" by Silverman-Tate(basic version not the "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by Silverman-Tate) And I am trying to solve for cubic curve, $y^2=x^3+px$ where $p$ is prime

1) Rank of the curve is $0,1$ or$ 2$.

Using the standard methods described in that book. 
I am considering various equations of the form $N^2 = b1M^4+b2e^4$ where $b_1.b_2=b$ to check if there is any solutions modulo $p$ and considering quadratic residue modulo $p$.

I know that this same questions were asked previously but currently I am not familiar with the content of "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" by Silverman-Tate)". So I need to prove what is currently in "Rational Points on Elliptic Curves" (by Silverman-Tate).

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

This is proved in Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" on page 311. The rank $r(E)$ of $E:y^2=x^3+px$ for $p$ prime is given as follows:
$$
r(E)= \begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } p\equiv 7,11 \bmod 16 \\
 0 \text{ or }1, \text{ if } p\equiv 3,5,13,15 \bmod 16 \\
 0 \text{ or }1 \text{ or }2, \text{ if } p\equiv 1,9 \bmod 16 
\end{cases}
$$
You can compare with the book by Silverman-Tate, in order to see which theorems are available.

Edit. After searching I found the question you have mentioned:

[Rank of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+px$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338657/rank-of-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x3px)