# how to calculate rank of elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I study about elliptic curve and I saw
[Rank of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+px$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338657/rank-of-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x3px)
but i can't understand how he can calculate
$$2M^4−2pe^4=N^2$$
$$4M^4−pe^4=N^2$$

how he revived to this formulas? what mean of $e, M, N$?

Comment: The technique you are after is called "descent by 2-isogeny".